# How can I get more than 100 rows of information using pandas read_html in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

I have been trying to import a table that I have in google sheets that has more than 100 rows of data, but the read_html funcion only read the first 100, how can I expand or set this limit of rows?

```py
A = pd.read_html('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqqSwGUvYAA33eV_B93nPtOQshZ2TIf8XGgkc90lnpQ/view#gid=0')
C = np.array((np.array(A[0]))[2:,7:12])
C[0,0:3] = ("Día", "Vacunas a 0:00", "Vacunas Día")
F = np.zeros((99,5)) 
for i in range(1,98):     
  for j in range(1,5):
    F[i,j] = float(C[i,j])       
F = np.nan_to_num(F)
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't tell you anything.  Why are you using `read_html`?  Are you scraping the web site?  If so, why?  Google has a complete and powerful API to let you access Google Sheets files directly.  In a browser, your files are displayed a page at a time and you'll have to scroll to get the rest.

Comment: @TimRoberts
You're right, my code is the following

`A=pd.read_html('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqqSwGUvYAA33eV_B93nPtOQshZ2TIf8XGgkc90lnpQ/view#gid=0')

C=np.array((np.array(A[0]))[2:,7:12])

C[0,0:3]=("Día","Vacunas a 0:00","Vacunas Día")

F=np.zeros((99,5))
for i in range(1,98):
    for j in range (1,5):
        F[i,j]=float(C[i,j])
     
F=np.nan_to_num(F)`

Its a code to import the data and turn it into an array of float through which I do further operations.
I dont really know much about the API you're talking about, but surely will look into it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display settings with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_rows',1000)
data = pd.read_html(url)
```

Comment: Actually i tried with that, but for some reason the read_html function does not change with that, for what I have used, it works just fine with read_csv and read_excel, thanks though! @lbal

Answer (score 0):

Try using this form:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

worksheet = gc.open('Your spreadsheet name').sheet1

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)

# Convert to a DataFrame and render.
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

from:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/sheets.ipynb#scrollTo=JiJVCmu3dhFa